# Finding and simulating a click on a system tray icon?

Tags: windows, winapi, click, contextmenu, system-tray

I need to figure out how to programmatically find and select a context menu item from a separate application's system tray icon. The only way I could imagine accomplishing this was to use mouse_event() with some hard-coded x/y values, and set the icon to always be shown. Aside from the hacky use of hard-coding in general, the problem here is the assumption that the icon will retain it's position (which is likely to break any time another application loads/unloads). I was wondering if anybody knew any other way to go about this?

Comment: Use UI Automation. The notification icons are accessible children of the notification area.

Comment: Is that a standard part of the .NET framework? I can't seem to find any proper namespace for it in the object browser, and it doesn't appear to be well documented online.

Comment: The catch with using UIA is that you have to be very aware of the actual UI layout - for example, if a icon is hidden, you'd need to know to find and click the "Show hidden icons" link first to access it. Also, the structure of the UI is always subject to change between Windows releases, so it can be fragile. But that's likely an issue with any solution to the qu above anyhow; using UIA is still far less fragile than hardcoded locations!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how the application has been written, selecting the item from the context menu will cause a `WM_COMMAND` message to be posted to a window belonging to the application. You can use a tool like Spy++ to check for this. If this is the case then all you would have to do (in theory) is simulate that message.

If the application does not use `WM_COMMAND` to receive selections from the context menu, your job is much harder. There is no documented method of discovering the position and identify of system tray items, and so your method of hard-coding the x/y values is probably the best option you have.

Comment: I just checked, and luckily yes it does. And it appears the WPARAM is passing the correct EN_SETFOCUS and EN_KILLFOCUS notifications. So what next? Retrieve the system tray handle, enumerate it's buttons, then use SetWindowsHookEx on the desired button and send a WM_COMMAND message?

Comment: No you shouldn't need to go to those lengths at all! Using Spy++ work out what the class and title are of the window the message is sent to, and then you can use `FindWindowEx` to find that window yourself and post it the message. Hopefully the tray icon needn't come into it at all.

Comment: The buttons aren't showing up in Spy++... at least not as a child of the system tray window, which is a ToolbarWindow32 named "User Promoted Notification Area" and so AFAIK you would need to use that window to get information about it's relevant buttons, using the methods described in Mark Hall's links (which I am still testing out).

Comment: When you select a command from the context menu, the `WM_COMMAND` message will be posted to the window that owns the tray icon. It doesn't actually go to the tray window at all. You need to stop thinking of this as a tray menu command and start thinking of it as a menu belonging to an application that just happens to be triggered from the tray menu.

Comment: I realize this, but I'm saying that the individual buttons on the ToolbarWindow32 do not show up in Spy++, so you cannot use FindWindowEx to get their corresponding handles. I'll just have to read up on API methods dealing with ToolbarWindow32 windows to see if I can get button/menu information, and continue on from there.

Comment: Why do you want the individual buttons to show up on Spy++? Forget about ToolbarWindow32 - it's not relevant at all to this.

Comment: If that's true, then how would I gather information about the application's context menu items _while the window itself is closed_? i.e., captions, enabled/disabled states, etc... In order to know exactly if and where to send the WM_COMMAND message? If the window is closed and only has a tray icon, the window doesn't exist in Spy++ and FindWindow will fail.
But if I focus on sending messages to the toolbar, then I should have access to the entire application's menu system.

Comment: A tray icon can't exist without a window to own it, just because it is not visible on screen does not mean it is not there. The window class and window title will almost certainly always be the same. Use Spy++ to find out what they are. Hard-code those strings into your application, and then your application can call `FindWindowEx` to find the window and post it the messages.

Comment: This may normally be the case... But for my target app, it doesn't work when the window's application is closed. FindWindow returns 0, and EnumWindows never finds it either. I have now triple-checked this. I even implemented a method which allows for wildcard searches, and once again it only found the window when it was open. Visibility has nothing to do with it, of course, but I'm telling you that when I click the target app's close [X] button, it cannot be found via FindWindow/EnumWindows until you reopen it from the system tray icon.

Comment: Wait... scratch that, it appears that my implementation of EnumWindows does NOT include child windows. Working on a fix... Thanks for all your help so far, btw!

Comment: @JonathanPotter And a few years later - _how_ do you use Spy++ to discover the window? The Find Window drag options don't work. They aren't children of the Tray windows.

Comment: @NetMage Use the message view to watch `WM_COMMAND` messages and see which window it gets posted to.

Comment: @NetMage Spy++ lets you monitor all windows in the system. You don't need to know the process.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I see that now - it wasn't very obvious to me in my version of Spy++, and x86 versus x64 didn't help - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

See this [MSDN Forum article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/4c4f60ce-3573-433d-994e-9c17f95187f0/) which discusses how to find the systemTray's Handle. The article then references a [CodeProject Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10497/A-tool-to-order-the-window-buttons-in-your-taskbar) on how to find the handle of the application you are searching for.  I have not tried this but it looks like it might be a viable starting point.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Gonna test it out real quick and update you with my results.

Comment: The code from the CodeProject article doesn't seem to allocate anything in the dwData parameter of a given TBBUTTON. After reading process memory (on Win7), this value is zero. I can confirm that it does find the correct button handles, and even allocates the correct tooltip text for each, but without the actual window handle of the buttons there is no way to programmatically use their context menus.