# How to right-click on system tray in application?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, simulation

I have a WPF application which has a tray icon and on right-click displays menu.
How I can from an other application (WPF, WinForms, C++) simulate right-click and then click menu?

Comment: Are you looking for a tutorial?

Comment: I am trying to find at least the way: how to do it?

Comment: Given that C# windows programming does not expose one to the "real working" of windows internals too much and that the problem in itself is non trivial - no downvote here. While I know the first... I would not know how to handle the menu click. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250362/finding-and-simulating-a-click-on-a-system-tray-icon has a starting point, but it is not really dealing with the menu side.

Comment: Thank you, your link contains a link  to codeproject article. I have tried it but it does not work in Windows 10

Comment: I think you can use this to find the icon: https://github.com/rzhw/SuperNotifyIcon

Comment: And then this to make a right click: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272681/how-can-i-simulate-a-mouse-click-at-a-certain-position-on-the-screen

Answer (score 1):

You must search for Simulate mouse and keyboard events

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548(v=vs.100).aspx

You can track user activity

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C